# Connection to a PostgreSQL through PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

It just stays at the ... or die ("Can't Connect"); and nothing else happens, but I know that everything is right on the Connection String

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    echo "Teste Inicio"; //To see if it can reach this part of code

    $conn_string = "host='localhost' port='5432' dbname='name_db' user='user_pgsql' password='passuser_pgsql'"; //Connection String
    $db_conn = pg_connect($conn_string) or die("Can't Connect");

    echo "Teste Depois Conexão"; //To see if it can reach this part of code

    $stat = pg_connection_status($db_conn);
    echo $stat;


    if ($db_conn)
    {
        echo "Teste Conectou"; //Echo to see if it has connected
            $query = "SELECT idgestores FROM gestores"; //Query
            echo "<br>"."Conexão bem sucedida"; //Connection Successfully
            $result = pg_query($db_conn, $query);
            while($row = pg_fetch_row($result))
            {
                echo "<br>"."ID: $row[0]   Nome: $row[1]";
                echo "<br>";         
            }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Teste Erro"; //Error
        echo "Erro de Ligação"; //Error
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try reomove the simple quotes on dsn (`$conn_string`)

Comment: Are you sure that `user_pgsql` doesn't have to use password?

Comment: I removed the simple quotes, and still nothing

Comment: Password is there is: passuser_pgsql

Comment: Try enabling `log_connections` on the PostgreSQL server and see if anything gets written to the server log.

Comment: I'm working on cPanel where can I enable that?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Look comment before please

Comment: On the database server.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I can't see anything that can change to make that work

Comment: I can't see nothing wrong with the connection, only the simple quotes, should be like this: `"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=name_db user=user_pgsql password=passuser_pgsql";`. You should check your parameters or the database itself.

Comment: You log into the database server machine, become the PostgreSQL user, edit `postgresql.conf` and set `log_connections = on`. Then you run `pg_ctl reload`. Then you run your program. Then you look into the log file, which you can find by examining the database parameters `log_directory` and `log_filename`.